# adding multiple inputs to array

Tags: php, html, ajax

Hi there I'm running into the following problem:

I have a form that gets loaded with Ajax with a couple of input field that must have the same name. What I'm trying to do is to add the values from the input fields to an array so I can send it with ajax to php. The problem is, I only get the value from the first input (so it doesn't add to the array)

AJAX:

```
$(target).find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
        quantity    = $("input[name='item_item_quantity[]']").val();
        meters      = $("input[name='item_item_meters[]']").val();
        data = {siteNumber : siteNumber, itemId : itemId, item_quantity : quantity, meters : meters};   

});
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
        }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input name="item_item_quantity[]" type="text" class="input calcInput">
<input name="item_item_quantity[]" type="text" class="input calcInput">
<input name="item_item_quantity[]" type="text" class="input calcInput">

<input name="item_item_meters[]" type="text" class="input calcInput">
<input name="item_item_meters[]" type="text" class="input calcInput">
<input name="item_item_meters[]" type="text" class="input calcInput">
```

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: Use `.each` and generate object?

Comment: Should be just as easy to make quantity and meters into an array and add to that array right? The problem is that it doesn't add to the array but it only picks up the first value from the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("input[name='item_item_quantity[]']").val();` returns value of **first** element of a set. You can read it in a [manual](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

If you want all values from set of elements, iterate this set, for example:

```
var vals = [];
$("input[name='item_item_quantity[]']").each(function() {
    vals.push($( this ).val());
});
```